# How to get name of server that has served request in fronted section?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I need to add server name in response HTTP headers X-Servedby.
Is there any way to replace [server] with name of server that has served request?

```
frontend front x.x.x.x:80
  default_backend balancing
  rspadd X-Servedby:\ [server] #I need to replace [server]

backend balancing
  server srv1 x.x.x.x:80 check
  server srv2 x.x.x.x:80 check
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve this, change the `frontend` stanza to the following:

```
frontend front x.x.x.x:80
    default_backend balancing
    acl srv1 srv_id 1
    acl srv2 srv_id 2
    rspadd X-Servedby:\ srv1 if srv1
    rspadd X-Servedby:\ srv2 if srv2
```

However, a better scaling alternative would be to use `cookie` in the `backend` stanza:

```
backend balancing
    cookie SRVNAME insert
    server srv1 x.x.x.x:80 cookie srv1 check
    server srv2 x.x.x.x:80 cookie srv2 check
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `rspadd X-Servedby:\ srv1 if srv1` is causing `error detected while parsing a 'rspadd' condition`. I suppose that srv1 in this condition should be defined as ACL, but it seems impossible to define ACL depending on server name. About cookies - this method will cause all requests that have cookie SRVNAME=srv1 to be served by srv1 server isn't it?

Comment: I've just found `srv_id` that could be used in ACL.

Comment: Sorry, not at my desk. Hope it gives you an idea at least. I will double check my config when I get to my desk.

Comment: Great! Please add defining `id 1`, `id 2` to `server` directive.

Comment: @Belin, thank you! I've posted more complex config for someone solving the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

We should use `srv_id` which provides `id` value defined for `server`

```
frontend front x.x.x.x:80

  acl serve_us1 url_beg /west
  acl serve_us2 url_beg /east

  #defining acl for srv_id
  acl served_by_us1 srv_id 1  #look at srv_id
  acl served_by_us2 srv_id 2  #look at srv_id

  use_backend us1 if serve_us1
  use_backend us2 if serve_us2 
  default_backend balancing

  rspadd X-ServedBy:\ us1 if served_by_us1
  rspadd X-ServedBy:\ us2 if served_by_us2

backend us1
  server srv1 1.1.1.1:80 check id 1 #look at id

backend us2
  server srv2 2.2.2.2:80 check id 2 #look at id

backend balancing
  server srv1 1.1.1.1:80 check id 1 #look at id
  server srv2 2.2.2.2:80 check id 2 #look at id
```